# Finite cover with zero symmetric difference

Tags: measure-theory

The original problem is following: Let J be a finite subinterval in $\mathbb{R}$ and A be a measurable subset of J. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite union of intervals B such that $d(A,B) = \mu^*((A - B) \cup (B - A)) < \epsilon$

I have solved this problem (posted below if you need hints). I try to put more restriction on B, that is, $B \supset A$. I have tried this problem for a while but without success. Could anyone help me with that problem? I feel I come really close to the solution, but somehow I still miss some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with the restriction $B\supset A$.  For example, if $A=\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, then for every finite union of intervals $B$ such that $B\supset A$, you can show that $d(A,B)=\mu(B)\geq 1$.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now. Thanks very much!